# Problem serializing and deserializing ArrayList

Tags: java, android, serialization, arraylist

Anytime I try to serialize a file I get the error: FileNotFound. Not sure why. Here is my FileHelper code:

```
package org.stocktwits.helper;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutput;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.stocktwits.model.Quote;

public class FileHelper {
    // Returns the contents of the file in a byte array.
    public static byte[] getBytesFromFile(File file) throws IOException {
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);

        // Get the size of the file
        long length = file.length();

        // You cannot create an array using a long type.
        // It needs to be an int type.
        // Before converting to an int type, check
        // to ensure that file is not larger than Integer.MAX_VALUE.
        if (length > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
            // File is too large
        }

        // Create the byte array to hold the data
        byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)length];

        // Read in the bytes
        int offset = 0;
        int numRead = 0;
        while (offset < bytes.length
               && (numRead=is.read(bytes, offset, bytes.length-offset)) >= 0) {
            offset += numRead;
        }

        // Ensure all the bytes have been read in
        if (offset < bytes.length) {
            throw new IOException("Could not completely read file "+file.getName());
        }

        // Close the input stream and return bytes
        is.close();
        return bytes;
    }

    public static void serializeQuotes(ArrayList<Quote> quotes){
        try {
            // Serialize to a file
            ObjectOutput out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("quotes.ser"));
            out.writeObject(quotes);
            out.close();

            // Serialize to a byte array
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream() ;
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos) ;
            out.writeObject(quotes);
            out.close();

            // Get the bytes of the serialized object
            //byte[] buf = bos.toByteArray();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void deserializeQuotes(ArrayList<Quote> quotes){
        try {
            // Deserialize from a file
            File file = new File("quotes.ser");
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
            // Deserialize the object
            quotes = (ArrayList<Quote>) in.readObject();
            in.close();

            // Get some byte array data
            byte[] bytes = FileHelper.getBytesFromFile(file);
            // see Reading a File into a Byte Array for the implementation of this method

            // Deserialize from a byte array
            in = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
            quotes = (ArrayList<Quote>) in.readObject();
            in.close();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Ah, I remember doing something like this before. In the end we just gave up and implemented our own (de)serialization methods.

Comment: Can you include the stack trace?

Comment: Please replace `System.out.println(e);` by `e.printStackTrace()` or just `throw e`.

Comment: @NullUser: you wrote your own serialization because you couldn't open a file?

Comment: @EJP No, because the object couldn't be deserialized correctly.

Comment: Exactly, so your comment was somewhat misleading. Also the proper solution would have been to fix thenobjetc concerned.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
private void serializeQuotes(){
        FileOutputStream fos;
        try {
            fos = openFileOutput(Constants.FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            oos.writeObject(quotes); 
            oos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void deserializeQuotes(){
        try{
            FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(Constants.FILENAME);
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            quotes = (ArrayList<Quote>) ois.readObject();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Actually you solved it by fixing the cause of the FileNotFoundException, which didn't have anything to do with this code, huge improvement though it is.

Comment: Yeah, Context.MODE_PRIVATE solves the FileNotFoundException for Android