# Simple manner pass arraylist between activity and intent

Tags: android, android-intent, arraylist

I am learning Android (I'm VERY newbie at the moment). 
I was looking and reading another posts but I have not find this exactly (or not simple).
I want to pass a arraylist from an activity to a intent service, I think this is the simplest manner to do it; however I get NullPointer Exception.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private static final String TAG = "Main";
ArrayList<String> lista_actual = new ArrayList<String>();
...
    public void onClick (View v) {
    Intent msgIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MiIntentService.class);
    lista_actual.add("probasndo cad");
    lista_actual.add("dfafsadf");
    lista_actual.add("dfasf");
    msgIntent.putStringArrayListExtra("lista", lista_actual);
    msgIntent.putExtra("iteraciones", 10);
    startService(msgIntent);
    //copiar();

}});
```

Then where I try get the array:

```
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) 
{

ArrayList<String> lista_archivos = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("lista_actual");
Log.d ("Intent", Integer.toString(lista_archivos.size()));
.
.
.
```

Thanks.

Comment: Also you can use `static ArrayList` to achieve same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you are fetching your array list in intent service ur calling wrong key, it should be :

```
ArrayList<String> lista_archivos = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("lista");
Log.d ("Intent", Integer.toString(lista_archivos.size()));
```

Replace lista_actual with lista.

Comment: Yes, I see it a few seconds ago (I don't wait for a reply so soon). Thanks, and yes, what stupid!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to serialize the arraylist in order to pass between activities. Further help will be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4670215/how-to-serialize-arraylist-on-android). Hope that helps