# How can I store each date picked from datepicker into memory or database on Android?

Tags: java, android, date, datepicker

I have created a datepicker where the user can pick a from and to date using the borax12 library. This opens a dialog where the user can set a date and when they press Ok it will set the date into this method:

```
 @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePickerDialog view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth,int yearEnd, int monthOfYearEnd, int dayOfMonthEnd) {
        to.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        to.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
        to.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);

        from = Calendar.getInstance();
        from.set(Calendar.YEAR, yearEnd);
        from.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYearEnd);
        from.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonthEnd);

        String date = "You picked the following date: From- "+dayOfMonth+"/"+(++monthOfYear)+"/"+year+" To "+dayOfMonthEnd+"/"+(++monthOfYearEnd)+"/"+yearEnd;
        dateTextView.append(new StringBuilder().append(date) + "\n");
    }
```

This works fine as the dates get appended to the dateTextView. But how can I store each date into an arraylist each time and into memory on the users phone or a database?

Comment: Near duplicate by same author hours apart: [How can I continuously check if the dates entered to and from are equal to the current date for the next year?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46025288/642706)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply create an Arraylist (`List<String> list= new Arraylist()`) when initializing the class and use list.add() whenever you need. It will create multiple instances of Strings inside your list.

You can save to [SharedPreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-example) or a DB like [SqLite](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/) (or even to a file or Server), decide what you want.

Comment: Thanks if I use SharedPreferences and the user closes all the apps on their phone will this data still be stored?

Comment: Yes, that is the whole point of Shared Preferences, to keep data even if user closes the app and re-open. If you must keep the data even if app is uninstalled, try referring to keep the code on a file (Which can be deleted as well from File Manager on phone if it is not private) or a remote Server.

Answer (score 2):

The `Calendar` class is now legacy, supplanted in Java by the java.time classes. For Android, see bullets below.

For a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone, use `LocalDate`.

```
LocalDate from = LocalDate.of( year , monthOfYear , dayOfMonth ) ;
```

To get a new value based on an existing value, use a [`TemporalAdjuster`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html). The class [`TemporalAdjusters`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html) provides several handy implementations. Apparently you would want [`lastDayOfYear`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html#lastDayOfYear--).

```
LocalDate to = from.with( TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfYear() ) ;
```

For Java, I would suggest tracking this pair of `LocalDate` objects using the [`LocalDateRange`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/LocalDateRange.html) class found in the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project. But that code is not back-ported to Android. You might want to create your own simple version of that class to combine the pair.

```
package com.example.javatimestuff;

import org.threeten.bp.Duration;
import org.threeten.bp.LocalDate;

public class DateRange
{

    private LocalDate start, stop;
//    private Duration duration ;  // Cache value if calling `getDuration` frequently.
//    private String stringed ; // Cache value if calling `toString` frequently.

    public DateRange ( LocalDate startArg , LocalDate stopArg )
    {
        this.start = startArg;
        this.stop = stopArg;
    }

    public LocalDate getStart ()
    {
        return this.start;
    }

    public LocalDate getStop ()
    {
        return this.stop;
    }

    public Period toPeriod ()
    {
        Period p = Period.between( this.start , this.stop );
        return p;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString ()
    {
        // Per ISO 8601 standard.
        // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_intervals
        String s = this.start.toString() + "/" + this.stop.toString();
        return s;
    }

    static public LocalDate parse ( String input ) {  // Obviously in real work you would make this safer: check for nulls, check for empty string, check for two parts, catch `DateTimeParseException`.
        String[] parts = input.split( "/" );
        LocalDate start = LocalDate.parse( parts[0]) ;
        LocalDate stop = LocalDate.parse( parts[1]) ;
        DateRange dr = new DateRange(start , stop ) ;
        return dr ;
    }
}
```

Call that class by constructor.

```
DateRange dr = new DateRange( from , to ) ;
```

Store in a `List` of type `DateRange`, our custom class.

```
List<DateRange> ranges = new ArrayList<>() ;
ranges.add( dr ) ;
```

For storage, [serialize the `List`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4670215/how-to-serialize-arraylist-on-android).  See: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) & [Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/objects/serial.html).

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: Thanks for this, it looks good and what i'm looking for. I can't find it anywhere how can I compile the ThreeTen-Extra library into build.gradle on Android? Also if I serialize the Arraylist can this still be accessed if the user closes the app?

Comment: @Samantha Read the links I posted. One on How to use ThreeTenABP, and one on serializing. Also: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) & [Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/objects/serial.html).

Comment: Ahh thanks so ThreeTenABP is the same as ThreeTen-Extra? I read that it's basically the same as using Joda time on android. https://peirr.com/jodatime-vs-threetenabp-android-datetime-tool-comparison/

Comment: @Samantha Again, I already addressed that in this Answer. I strongly suggest you slow down, read more, post less. For discussion, see [JavaRanch.com](https://javaranch.com).