# Serialize ArrayList<ArrayList<MyPoint>> isnt working

Tags: java, android, serialization, arraylist

Having a ArrayList>, how do I serialize?

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<MyPoint>> polygons;

        try {
            FileOutputStream fileOut = openFileOutput("polygons.ser", MODE_PRIVATE);
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
            out.writeObject(pv.polygons);
            out.close();
            fileOut.close();
            Log.d("Polygons Output", pv.polygons.toString());
            Log.d("Polygons Output Out", out.toString());
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        try {
            FileInputStream fileIn = openFileInput("polygons.ser");
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
            ArrayList<ArrayList<MyPoint>> arr = new ArrayList<>();
            pv.polygons = (ArrayList<ArrayList<MyPoint>>) in.readObject();
            in.close();
            fileIn.close();
        } catch (IOException io) {
            io.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Log.d shows me ArrayList of [[Point(0,0) ,....]].

The outputStream is in onSaveInstance and the inputStream is in onCreate().
MyPoint extends Point implements Serializable...

Why does it not work?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3589069/794088 might help

Comment: Point implements Parcelable, you can also have MyPoint to do the same.

Comment: The task is to serialize it, I know that Point implements Parcelable but this is not my task :(
So yea... thats why MyPoint implements Serializable